# To get records in between two date in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql

See the below table,
In this date column type is varchar not date.

```
           |---------------------|
           |date       |   name  |
           |---------------------|
           |23-5-2005  | babi    |
           |20-6-2005  | ram     |
           |12-5-2005  | jhon    |
           |1-5-2004   | babi    |
           |23-5-2005  | guru    |
```

Know I want to get records between two dates.

```
String gt = "12-5-2005";
String gt1 = "20-6-2005";
String query = ??;
```

How can I write the query to get names between strings gt and gt1

Comment: you want to use `str_to_date(your_date_here, '%d/%m/%Y')` this will cast the varchar to a date, so that you can make it query-able. your query would be `SELECT date, name FROM tbl WHERE date BETWEEN first_date AND last_date`

Comment: haha nice.. glad I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL portion should would work like below.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    StackOverflow.`Table`
 WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN 
    STR_TO_DATE('12-5-2005', '%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('20-6-2005', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: Great answer!  You caught the column name and I spaced on that one. +1

Answer (score 2):

Date between and str_to_date will do it.

Thanks to @John Ruddell for the str_to_date syntax. :)

```
SELECT
  name,
  date
FROM table
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE("12-05-2005", '%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE("20-06-2005", '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: :) im not a fan of hardcoding a date though, so I figured i would just comment and let the OP figure out a way to do the date as a variable

Comment: @JohnRuddell, usually dates are specifically set.  OP wants between two dates.

Comment: I know.. I meant I didn't want to write the date in there but let him figure out how to put the variable in there. aka `gt` and `gt1` --- gotta let them figure out some stuff since it helps them learn better :)

Comment: @paqogomez It giving empty set with warning 'Truncated  incorrect date value '12-5-2005'

Comment: you need your month to be two characters --- aka '12-05-2005'

Answer (score 0):

May be It'll help you :)

query='select * from tableName where date between "' + gt + '" and "' + gt1 + '" ';

Comment: if you didn't notice the OP said that the date is a varchar and not a datetime so this wouldn't work.

Comment: this is also java not php so it wouldn't be `$query`

Answer (score -1):

You need to use mysql STR_TO_DATE function

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

```
String query = "select name from table 
where 
      table.date > STR_TO_DATE(gt, '%d/%m/%y')
      AND 
      table.date < STR_TO_DATE(gt1, '%d/%m/%y')";
```

Comment: wouldn't `gt` and `gt1` not be in quotes? and there are no parenthesis () in the WHERE... as well as your parentesis do not match up (youre missing one)